# Change appearance of Mat-Form-Field in Angular 15

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, form-fields

I want to change the appearance of an Mat-Form-Field with the appearance "outline".

[image: It should look something like this]

So it should have a wihte background and white border.

We already tried using:

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none`

And then

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: white;
}
```

We also tried using `::ng-deep` even though its deprecated.

Last Resort would be to change the whole Angular theme.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141542/custom-style-material-input-without-ng-deep-important/73144861#73144861)  or this [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020318/angular-material-mat-form-field-input-field-icon/67044128#67044128) ?

Answer (score -2):

You should not update the design of a library. They're made to implement a design system. If you edit this design, what's the point of using the library ? Moreover, if you keep it up-to-date, it means you will have to update your code at every new version that changes the HTML of the component.

That aside, you should not de-encapsulate your components. This will definitely create side effects. Just put your overriding code in `styles.scss`.

Finally, assuming your CSS selector is correct, know that CSS selectors have what is called priority : a complex CSS selector will be applied first, compared to a simple one.

You can use this

```css
.myClass { background-color: white !important; }
```

If you have no other choice, but I would suggest to avoid it, and instead create a complex selector to increase its priority.

Comment: Please answer the question the OP asked rather than assume or advice on why they are doing it

Comment: I did answer on the issue. And I am free to give feedback on why this is a bad solution. I won't encourage bad practices.